# How to access a network folder to scan to with a HP printer on a Mac computer?

Tags: networking, macos, printer, network-printer, print-server

I have a HP printer and would like to scan to a network folder that I can access on multiple computers in the network. On the *HP Embedded Web  Server* (which you can open by typing the printers' IPv4 address in your internet browser), you can set a destination folder to scan to. It asks for the network path of a folder in the format `\\mypc\sharedfolder` (Windows pc with this folder). Scanned pages are stored in this folder, that can be accessed on the Windows computer.

Now I would like to access the same folder on a Mac computer in the network. I do not know to which server I can connect?
Could it be something of the form `smb://<printer IPv4 address>/<foldername>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax `smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` replace Xs with the IPv4 or the hostname. Then once you connect you will be prompted to select the share.

Comment: If I want to connect to `smb://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx` (the IPv4 address I found after printing the network settings of the printer, note that it consists of 11 numbers instead of 12), I obtain "Connection failed - There was an error connecting to the server "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx". Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. - If you are unable to resolte the problem contact your system administrator."

Comment: you need to use the Windows PC ip or name, not the printer.

Comment: I see. So now I need to find the IPv4 address of the golder on the Windows computer. It is D:\Folder but I have difficulties to find its IPv4 address using the Terminal.

Comment: ```ipconfig -all```